# KSQL select one row per group that corresponds to having the least timestamp

Tags: ksqldb, ktable

In KSQL is there a row_number kind of function that can be used in combination with TUMBLING WINDOW in order to group by and only get the event that corresponds to having the least timestamp within the group by thats used.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.

You can use the `LATEST_BY_OFFSET` aggregation, this may do what you're after.